# Auto Assign Case in SalesForce using Power Automate

Tags: salesforce, power-automate

Due to my user permission, I can not create any flow automation in SFDC neither create rules nor workflows - and the dedicated team in my company in charge of that is busy with other department queries.

Alternative option is Power Automation :
Attached is the flow I created, could you please support on how to assign a case from a queue (I have the correct SF object) to a user with a specific condition ?

As you can see, I blurred my queue name and the user name but here's what I'd like to automate :
_"OwnerID" is/contains : "xxxxxx" (which is a queue) AND "Country" contains/or equals : Finland

After this first step, I'm not sure how to create the flow to assign or change the OwnerID from the specific queue to a specific user "First name, last name"(blurred too).

Thanks for your support
[image]

Comment: After a first look I would say that the Record Id field should use the Case Id and not the Owner ID in the Update Record (v3) action. The owner/assigned user field might be listed under the show advanced options button of your Update Record (v3) action.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I'll try that out. 
Do you know whether I should use any specific action to make it works to change from queue owner to a specific User ? 
and how do I make the flow works ? does Save make it works directly through my Salesforce connector ? without any further action ?